# GGTS Groovy:Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class in DslBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I created a project from command line and have eight errors. I had previously done so from within Eclipse, had this error, so thought I would try it from outside just to be sure I wasn't doing something odd. Anyway, absolutely nothing done to the project except creating it. From the command line the project builds fine and runs fine, not that there is anything to test.

```
Environment:
Linux Mint 17
java version "1.8.0_05" 64-bit
Groovy Version: 2.3.3
Grails version: 2.4.1
```

I have installed the 2.3 compiler feature installed in Kepler. The java 8 libraries are installed, though the compiler level is set to 7. Grails version is as above. The Groovy compiler is likewise set to 2.3.

Searching has failed to turn up possible causes. I did find that the java compiler level was set to 1.4 after originally importing, but corrected that. What should I look at next?

Comment: Did you install the Groovy JDT Core Patch for Java 8?

Comment: The version is 2.9.0.xx-201406271927-e43. This is the same versions as the compiler and groovy-eclipse features. And, just to verify, I attempted to install GGTS for Kepler again. A message pops up stating that there is nothing to update. It seems I am good to go here.

Comment: I don't think you are good to go because this version of Greclipse (2.9.0.xx-201406271927-e43) doesn't have Java 8 support. You need something that has the JDT patch for e43 (qualifier ends with 'e43-j8') or something based on Eclipse 4.4. The error you are getting is likely because the JDT compiler doesn't understand Java 8 default methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a version of GGTS / Greclipse that has Java 8 support. I recommend you use GGTS 3.6.0 based on Eclipse 4.4 if you want decent Java 8 support.

The error you are getting is most likely something to do with the Java compiler not understanding about default methods in interfaces (this is a Java 8 feature).

GGTS 3.6.0 is on the verge of being released but until then you can get a snapshot from here:
http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html

Comment: I was trying to avoid the pain of going through an eclipse install. Not that much pain, of course, but getting everything configured the way I like does take time. So, I am going to install Luna then get the latest GGTS plugin. I will update after doing so.

Comment: An alternative is stick to JDK 7.

Comment: Reading through your question again: "The java 8 libraries are installed, though the compiler level is set to 7". This could actually be the problem. Java 7 compiler won't understand some 'default methods' in Java 8 libraries interfaces are actually implemented. So it is like to complain they are abstract.

Comment: I have not been able to get Kepler to recognize Java 8. I followed the instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler to apply patches. However, it failed to install the JDT patch. So, as I stated above, I am going to go to Luna.

Comment: Going backward to 1.7 is not a solution, imo.

Comment: I installed Luna (couldn't find a PPA - so manually), then installed the latest GGTS (3.6.0). Problem solved.